# Notebook does not open

Tags: notebooks

When I save a simple notebook , with the sum 2 + 2 , it does not open at all or with double-click or by pressing CTRL + O. Have reinstalled Mathematica 3 times and did not work. I put the settings in standard mode and also failed. The notebooks I saved not issue any messages when trying to open them , they just do not open.

Comment: I did not see that a duplicate existed.  Please edit this link into the other, identical question you asked.  Most people won't look in the comments, so make sure it's edited into the main post.  Also, it's best to use file hosting that doesn't require login.  Try for example http://ge.tt/.  I cannot download from your link because it requires social media login, which I'm not willing to do.